# How to solve "A RenderFlex overflowed by 19 pixels on the right."?

Tags: flutter-layout, render

I have a page as below, and I got error `A RenderFlex overflowed by 19 pixels on the right.`, I tried to add Expanded or SixedBox before Row or Column, but same result, what I can do? then I want know how can I show three dot in this case when text overflowed?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          ListTile(
             Row(
              children: [
                Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0), child: Column()),
                Column(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the result what I wondered as below:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          ListTile(
             Row(
              children: [
                Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0), child: Column()),
                Expanded(
                 child: Column([
                      Row(Expanded(
                        child: Text()),
                   ),
                 ]),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image]